# Custom date format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle12c

I have dates in VARCHAR column in a table with this format.

1. "2019-08-13 00:00:00"

And few are in this format

2. "Wed Feb 20 2019 15:00:58 GMT+0100"

I want all my fields to be in (2).

I cannot have date type for this column. Please help me in converting

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Give writing an `UPDATE ...` query a try. We can help you when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You say that this column can't be a `date`.  But if you are storing dates (or, in this case, timestamps with time zones), you really, really want that column to be the proper data type.  Otherwise, you're going to be setting yourself up for a world of pain when someone inserts a string in the wrong format.

Assuming all strings of length 19 are in the first format, they all represent valid dates, and you want all of them to end up in the GMT+1 time zone, something like

```
select case when length(column_name) = 19
            then to_char( to_date( column_name, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' ),
                          'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) || ' GMT+0100'
            else column_name
         end
  from your_table
```